# Prevent case sensitivity in formula

Tags: apex, formula-field

I was struck at a point where I want to populate a formula field in an object based on the billing state. I've tried below formula and it worked.

```
CASE( BillingState,
'AP', 'IST',
'TL', 'IST',
'ALASKA', 'EST',''
)
```

The field is taking only upper case letters. I want my field to accept values both in upper and lower case. Can someone help me on what needs to be added to my code snippet.

Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think using the UPPER() formula would do the job:
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_functions_i_z.htm&type=5

```
CASE( UPPER(BillingState),
'AP', 'IST',
'TL', 'IST',
'ALASKA', 'EST',''
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response and it worked.